# I am tryin to write Keith Galli's connect 4 code into different classes( each in a different .py file) and have difficulty passing to classes

Tags: python, object, inheritance, parameter-passing, python-class

I am trying to devide [Keith Galli's Connect 4 with minmax](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MMLtza3CZFM&t=3310s&ab_channel=KeithGalli) algorithm into classes, so far I came up with 5 classes. Game-view, Main, Board, Minmax and Pieces. I know the best way to go about this was to just make everthing from scratch and stuff but that is not the case. I went to my professor and he said that i should try to avoid using inheritance here. Could someonone help me to give me an idea of what i should do to get it working? The github link to the project and what i have changed so far is [here](https://github.com/M6AIP2022/finalproject-final-project-group-95.git) . My professor gave me the following tips: "make a seperate class for the piece (AI and player)","Dont use inheritance", "make game view class handle everything", "game view should have the board, tge game pieces and the players (PvP or PvAI)" and to do all of this by using object oriented programming. Anything that can help me in the righ direction helps, especially with passing of variables, methods of classes and the pieces and board because i cant find the right way to do it.

i have been using inheritance and importing but its confusing to go from a non-class program too a class program. it became a bit of a mess, with all the self, board and piece variables. I want to know which methods should be where and how i can pass teh methods, variables, board and pieces to eachother in a way that makes sense.

Comment: Your github link is private and can't be viewed. It would be better to paste the code inline. It would also help to post a link to the connect4 project repository. I think you're modeling your code after this project: https://github.com/KeithGalli/Connect4-Python

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.